# Optimization with convolution in the objective function

Tags: fourier-analysis, convex-optimization, convolution

I would like to minimize the following objective function

$$ 
\| H \ast A - (H \cdot I) \ast B \|_F^2
$$

w.r.t. $H$, where

- $H$, $I$, $A$, and $B$ are all square matrices of the same size ($I$ is a flipped identity matrix i.e., off-diagonal elements are 1 and others 0),
- $\ast$ denotes convolution and
- $\cdot$ is the matrix multiplication.

I would like to ask: are there any common routines to solve a problem involving convolution? Also, is this problem convex?

**Edit**:

I first considered to apply FFT on both $H \ast A$ and $ (H \cdot I) \ast B$. This however still cannot eliminate all convolution operations from the objective.

Comment: Are $H \ast A$ and $ (H \cdot I) \ast B$ linear (affine) functions of the elements of $H$? If so, this is just a linear least squares problem (even if transformation to standard form is "convoluted") , and is therefore  convex.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Why convolutions are affine functions?

Comment: Only need them to be affine w.r.t. H, (optimization variables), not with respect to the other matrices, which are input to the optimization problem.